# How to insert a back slash to a string and apply it as a section in Latex?

Tags: r, latex

Suppose I have a string like "`A_B_C`" and I would change it to "`A\_B\_C`" (not manually but using `R` maybe) and then apply it to  $\LaTeX$  section like `\section {A\_B\_C}`. I am asking this because I have a large number of data frames with names like "`A_B_C`" and want to find a best way for that to generate a `pdf` document.

Comment: some combination of `gsub` and `paste`..give it a try

Comment: May you give an example using "AB_C_D"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep:

```
x <- "A_B_C"
result <- paste0("\\section {",gsub("_","\\\\_",x),"}")
result
#[1] "\\section {A\\_B\\_C}"
cat(result)
#\section {A\_B\_C}
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice answers to my two questions! If you use Sweave or knitr, do you know whether I can make a latex section like :`<<>>= cat(result) @ ?`

Comment: @DadongZhang - you could yes. Experiment a little with changing the text in `paste` or `paste0` and you will see it is possible.